# R-studio console not taking any command

Tags: r, console, rstudio

I have intermediate experince in R.

I am stuck with this problem.My console is not showing ">" sign.Also when i command something,it doesn't show any output.I haven't opened.I haven't opened sink().

```
> View(temp1)
> Binary_data_withoutrecall <- temp
> View(Binary_data_withoutrecall)
> View(temp)


View(temp)
View(temp)
> temp <-binary






> temp$Scheduled_Time <- as.POSIXct(temp$Scheduled_Time , format = "%I:%M:%S %p")
View(temp)
save.image("~/RStudio/projects/noshow/saturday.RData")
savehistory("~/RStudio/projects/noshow/saturday.Rhistory")
> sink()
sink(NULL)
View(temp)
View(Binary_data_withoutrecall)
```

As you can see i also tried to save history and image .But I can't see any history file added in my working directory.

Comment: Session / Restart R, unless there's some reason you really don't want to.